# Are questions about tech level applications to scenarios on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I asked a question a little while back

[How long could someone with locked in syndrome survive in 1915](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/93885/how-long-could-someone-with-locked-in-syndrome-survive-in-1915)

While I did not word the question to say "in a 1915 like tech level world" the question would be identical with this wording.

I also see a questions like this:

[How long would it take to travel approximately 170 miles by foot?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/96049/how-long-would-it-take-to-travel-approximately-170-miles)

To me these questions seem similar.  Both want to know how something would work in a given tech level.

Are questions like this on topic here?

Answer (score 1):

Questions taking something from one tech-level and introducing it into another tech-level, where it is/was non-existent, are on-topic.

Questions about actions that have taken place in a previous tech-level are off-topic.

---

You have to build an element of a world if a question is supposed to be on-topic. In neither of the questions you linked I can see this element of a new world. As far as I can see the first one is asking about how a medical condition would have been treated in the past and the other one is asking about how long it would have taken to walk a certain distance in the past.

Both seem off-topic and therefore I voted off-topic on both of them.

Both are also about the actions of a character. How long would this person survive? How long would this character take?

Try to make it more general: How long would this unknown disease that was non-existent in this time period be treated according to the history of how people dealt with new diseases? How long would it take an adventuring group of x people to walk into terrain that looks like [sketch]?

Answer (score -3):

I haven't clicked through to the questions themselves, but I would find both those questions (as titled) on-topic.  To me, any question that covers a detail of a fictional world is on-topic.  The fictional world does not have to differ from our real world at all in my opinion.

Of course, others have a more narrow definition of scope.

Comment: Titles are there to provide a *limited* glimpse of the question. They cannot contain all the details of a question sufficiently, thus only reading the title without looking at the question body is one of the major problems on here. The title is but a label, yet many people seem to claim the title to be everything and the body of the question to be nothing....